# How to know when SendGatewayMessage fails

Tags: coldfusion

When using [SendGatewayMessage](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_s_02.html) it can sometimes fail if the "Maximum number of events to queue" setting (found in CF8 Admin > Event Gateways > Settings) is reached. I need to know when that happens, how can I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the following [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c1f.html):

> You can check on how many threads are
>   running and the maximum thread size,
>   especially useful if you find you
>   exceeding the 'Maximum number of
>   events to queue' and don't/can't
>   change it easily.

```
<cfset gatewayService = createObject("java", "coldfusion.eventgateway.GatewayServices").getGatewayServices()> 
<cfoutput> 
   Current: #gatewayService.getQueueSize()# 
   <br> 
   Max: #gatewayService.getMaxQueueSize()# 
</cfoutput>
```

[These classes appear to be documented a bit here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6041.html).