# A queue ahead of the queue

Tags: multithreading, coldfusion, queue, gateway

I am using the ColdFusion gateways to fire and forget a large number of actions. To do this, I have a loop that goes through a query with a `SendGatewayMessage()` at the end. However, the query that I loop through can get extremely large. (100.000+ records)

To prevent actions from being lost, I increased the queue size and the number of threads.

Because actions still got lost, I included a loop before the `SendGatewayMessage()` like so:

```
<cfloop condition="#gatewayService.getQueueSize()# GTE #gatewayService.getMaxQueueSize()#">
    <cfset guardianCount = guardianCount+1>
</cfloop>
<cflog file="gatewayGuardian" text="#i# waited for #guardianCount# iterations. Queuesize:#gatewayService.getQueueSize()#">
<cfset SendGatewayMessage("EventGateway",eventData)>
```

(More info on the gatewayService class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5236381/894974))

This is more or less acceptable, since I can increase the request timeout to a few hours(!), but I am still looking for a more effective way to slow down the sending of messages to the queue in the hope that the overall process will go faster with less pressure on the resources of the server.

Any suggestions?
Any thoughts on the consequences of increasing the queue size even further?

Comment: I'd look for ways to reduce the amount of data you are processing.

Comment: @DanBracuk That would be optimal, of course. But the amount of data to process is not really negotiable... I could try to cut it up, but the main thing I'm trying to do is process as many records possible with a request that's as short as possible....

Comment: If you really can't change `gatewayService`, there really isn't much you can do here. You could change the `<cfset...` to `<cfset variables.guardianCount++>` but I doubt that would make much difference

Comment: Can't you check the status of the send operation, and if failed, wait a bit and retry? Personally, I would break it up into reasonable sized *batches*.  ie Process all 100K, just not in one go.

Comment: @leigh: Yeah, i ended up using batches, making the last operation in a batch fire of an event to start the next one. It's not optimal, but still the best option I think.

Comment: @Sander - Why do you think it is sub-optimal? Even pulling 100K records at a time, does not mean they are all sent at once.  Assuming a single thread, the results should be similar.  Batch processing is usually a better option when dealing with large amounts of data, as it allows for greater control and more options (threading, etcetera).

Comment: @Leigh: The only reason that it's sub-optimal is because I had to make something that fires off the next batch at the end of the function started by the gateway. Still, I can see how this is the best and perhaps only option.

Comment: @Sander - Not sure about your exact structure, but in general the "lather, rinse, repeat " approach is appropriate for batch processes. You should post a brief summary of the final code as an answer, to close out the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, I use application variables to keep track of the records in the whole job, the number of batches already processed and the number of records processed.
At the start of the job, I have a piece of code that initiates all these variables like so:

```
<cfif not structKeyExists(application,"batchNumber") or application.batchNumber
 eq 0 or application.batchNumber eq "">
    <cfset application.batchNumber = 0>
    <cfset application.recordsToDo = 0>
    <cfset application.recordsDone = 0>
    <cfset application.recordsDoneErrors = 0>
</cfif>
```

After that, I set all the records in a query and determine which records in that query we need to process in the current batch.
The amount of records in the batch is determined by the total amount of records and the maximum queue size. This way, each batch will never occupy more than about half of the queue. This makes sure that the job will never interfere with other operations or jobs and that the initial request will not time out.

```
<cfset application.recordsToSync = qryRecords.recordcount>
<cfif not structKeyExists(application,"recordsPerBatch") or application.recordsPerBatch eq "" or application.recordsPerBatch eq 0>
    <cfset application.recordsPerBatch = ceiling(application.recordsToDo/(ceiling(application.recordsToDo/gatewayService.getMaxQueueSize())+1))>
</cfif>
<cfset startRow = (application.recordsPerBatch*application.batchNumber)+1>
<cfset endRow = startRow + application.recordsPerBatch-1>
<cfif endRow gt application.recordsToDo>
    <cfset endRow = application.recordsToDo>
</cfif>
```

Then I loop through the query with a from/to loop to fire off the gateway events. I kept the guardian so there will never be a record lost because the queue is full.

```
<cfloop from="#startRow#" to="#endRow#" index="i">
    <cfset guardianCount = 0>
    <!--- load all values from the record into a struct --->
    <cfset stRecordData = structNew()>
    <cfloop list="#qryRecords.columnlist#" index="columnlabel">
        <cfset stRecordData[columnlabel] = trim(qryRecords[columnlabel][i])>
    </cfloop>
    <cfset eventData = structNew()>
    <cfset eventData.stData = stRecordData>
    <cfset eventData.action = "bigJob">
    <cfloop condition="#gatewayService.getQueueSize()# GTE #gatewayService.getMaxQueueSize()#">
        <cfset guardianCount = guardianCount++>
    </cfloop>
    <cfset SendGatewayMessage("eventGateway",eventData)>
</cfloop>
```

Whenever a record is done, I have a function that checks the number of done vs the number of records to do. When they are the same, I'm done. Otherwise we may need to start a new batch.
Notice that the check to see if we're done is in a cflock, but the actual event post is not. This is because otherwise you might get a deadlock when the event you posted can't read the variables you use inside the lock.

I hope this is of use to someone or someone else has a better idea still.

```
<cflock timeout="30" name="jobResult">
    <cfset application.recordsDone++>
    <cfif application.recordsDone eq application.recordsToDo> 
        <!--- We are done. Set all the application variables we used back to zero, so they do not get in the way when we start the job again --->
        <cfset application.batchNumber = 0>
        <cfset application.recordsToDo = 0>
        <cfset application.recordsDone = 0>
        <cfset application.recordsPerBatch = 0>
        <cfset application.recordsDoneErrors = 0>
        <cfset application.JobStarted = 0>
        <!--- If the number of records we have done is the same as the number of records in a batch times the current batchnumber plus one, we are done with the batch. --->
    <cfelseif application.recordsDone eq application.recordsPerBatch*(application.batchNumber+1)
        and application.recordsDone neq application.recordsToDo>
        <cfset application.batchNumber++>
        <cfset doEventAnnounce = true>
    </cfif>
</cflock>
<cfif doEventAnnounce>
<!--- Fire off the event that starts the job. All the info it needs is in the applicationscope. --->
    <cfhttp url="#URURLHERE#/index.cfm" method="post">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="event" value="startBigJob">
    </cfhttp>
</cfif>
```

Comment: IMO, this kind of batch process should be db driven, so you only pull the data needed for the current batch ie X records, and the last known state persists even if the application restarts.